# Why is this custom WordPress loop not using my arguments?

Tags: php, wordpress

**Context:** I've created a popular posts widget that uses a meta field as the indicator of how popular the post is. This widget is bundled with a social media sharing plugin such that when they fetch the share counts for popular networks, it stores those counts into a meta field. We can then query that meta field to show popular posts based on how many times an article has been shared across social media.

**Code Sample:** This is a small sampling of the code that I'm using. Obviously, after this portion of the code, we close the while loop, close the conditional, reset the post query data, etc. The full content of this widget file can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/warfare-plugins/social-warfare/blob/master/functions/widgets.php The portion that you see below starts around line 330 of that file.

```
// If a custom timeframe is not being used....
    if( $timeframe == 0 ):

        // Create the arguments for a query without a timeframe
        $swp_args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $count,
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'meta_key'          => '_'.$network,
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
        );

    // If a custom timeframe is being used....
    else:

        // Create the arguments for a query with a timeframe
        $swp_args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $count,
            'post_type'         => 'post',
            'meta_key'          => '_'.$network,
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'date_query'        => array(
                'column'        => 'post_date',
                'after'         => '- '.$timeframe.' days'
            )
        );
    endif;

    // Reset the main query
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Query and fetch the posts
    $swq = new WP_Query( $swp_args );

    // Begin the loop
    if( $swq->have_posts() ) :
        $i = 1;
        while( $swq->have_posts() ):

            $swq->the_post();
```

**Problem:** We have this plugin on just over 5,000 sites. However, on a small handful of sites, it does NOT use our custom query, but instead it uses the default WordPress query. In these cases, it returns the most recent posts and it returns the number of posts based on the WordPress posts per page setting. In fact, on one site, for example, it works perfect on one page, but on archive/category pages, it reverts to using the WordPress default loop instead of my custom query.

I wonder if their is another plugin or theme that has added some hooks or whatnot to the WordPress query and that is overriding my custom arguments.

The only thing I've tried so far is adding the wp_reset_postdata() before and after my query, but it didn't seem to fix anything.

**Question:** Is there any way that I can run this custom query, and guarantee that it runs the custom query and never runs the default WordPress query?

Comment: Let me respond to that by quoting what I said in the original post: "Obviously, after this portion of the code, we close the while loop, close the conditional, reset the post query data, etc. The full content of this widget file can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/warfare-plugins/social-warfare/blob/master/functions/widgets.php"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) it looks like `date_query` is defined as of [version 3.7](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.7) in the `WP_Query` date parameter list. It's possible that these subset of sites, on which this query does not work, are not using Wordpress version 3.7 or later.

The only other thing I can think of where this bug would appear sometimes and not other times would be using [really old/outdated versions of PHP](http://php.net/eol).

For example `strtotime('- 180 days')` would produce inconsistent results on versions of PHP < 5.1.2 as you can see here from [this 3v4l.org test](https://3v4l.org/SHqtu). It's highly unlikely, but since it appears to be a very small subset of sites where it's not working and given that nothing else is obviously wrong with the code this would be my best educated guess.

To get more consistent behavior across the board you should use `strtotime('-180 days')` instead, so modify your query parameters to `'after' => '-'.$timeframe.' days'`

Comment: Good observation. However, on one site where I was just testing, I set the $timeframe to both 0 and 180 for two tests. When set to 0 it will use the query without the date_query parameter. Neither worked. Additionally, I just checked one of the sites with this issue and they are indeed running WP 4.5.x.

Comment: Are you saying this code doesn't work at all on any version of WP that you've tested it on? Or are you saying it works sometimes but not other times?

Comment: This code is on 5,000+ sites. It only doesn't work on about 2 or 3 of them.

Comment: Have you managed to consistently reproduce the buggy behavior on those 2 or 3 sites? What's different about them? What versions of WordPress do they run? What versions of PHP do they run? Can you consistently reproduce the bug there?